# Is there a way to silent install a vb6 or a .NET(preferebly C#) application?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

I tried to do a silent install of a setup.exe of a vb6 application with command line setup.exe /s but this still shows the gui. I dont want the gui show i want it completely silent. If there is an easy way to do it in vb6 and in .NET apps would help a lot(but keep in mind it shouldnt show any gui). While google-ing i found somewhere said that i should create an installer myself. So if there is no other way please let me know if you have the right reference to do it.

Comment: What did you use to make the setup file?

Comment: i used the microsoft's package and deployment wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) to generate a MSI file, and then run [msiexec](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/msiexec.mspx?mfr=true) with the /qn switch.

It works for .NET applications as well. In fact, it would work with pretty much anything you throw at it.

Comment: Thatnks mate, i was looking for something simpler but this did it anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

In VB an application setup created with the **Package And Deployment Wizard** is run in silent mode with the command-line switch **-s c:\mydir\myapp.log** where c:\mydir\myapp.log is the required log file. See the full list of options [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182470)

Comment: Yes i tried that but still shows the gui of the automated installer. i dont want that

Comment: Did you specify a log file after the switch? It is required.

Comment: Yes of course it was installed properly as it is supposed to do. everything worked. my problem is is how to do the same thing but the gui not showing. it is show for like 1 second but still i need that not to be there at all.

Comment: @cArn See if this [MSDN Link Helps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190046)

Comment: @MarkHall i read the article but nothing really helped, also i checked the net for info about silent and unattended installation, and silent installation method its supposed to be silent and nothing shows up, but in my case its like an unattended installation because the gui of the installation shows up for like 2 seconds

Comment: @cArn If my memory serves me correctly, Microsoft shipped a limited version of Install Sheild for VS6, it was on the VS installation Disks, I moved my VB6 applications to that because of issues with the Package and Deployment wizard. They also released Microsoft Installer as an Add On to Visual Interdev that is what I finally ended up using... But you will really have to search for that since Microsoft doesn't support it any more.

Comment: @cArn There are also some free installers out there, Inno Setup is one example and can be found at http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php